# How to read a line with integers reversed?

Tags: c++, file, integer, int

i have a file with one line with integers
ex:

---

6 4 3 6 4

---

and i have a while loop that reads the file
ex:

```
int n;
while(file >> n)
{
     //stuff with int
}
```

Now this is supposed to read the file by the begining to the ending
How can i make it to read the file reversed
?

Comment: Don't read reversed. Change the order after reading at last. OR: If you know the count of numbers use an array with in index counting down to zero.

Comment: Read the file to which ever data-structure you want and perform operations on it instead of reading the file from the end

Comment: Read the values into a `std::vector<int>` and apply [`std::reverse()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: Process the data in reverse, that way it doesn't matter which order it is in.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int
main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    for (int tmp; cin >> tmp;)
        v.push_back(tmp);
    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (auto x : v)
        cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Can be executed with a file (`$ bin < file`) or the values can be typed in if no file is provided.
If you don't want this feature, just change the reading of the values. Note: range for loop and auto requires `-std=c++11` to compile.